# Android Studio XML clickable areas needed in Imageview

Tags: android

In my app I want to create many clickable areas in an Imageview. I try place button on imageview (by using margintop,marginleft etc..). But in different phones(according to it's size) these buttons displays on different positions..

So what should I do to make Clickable areas in my ImageView....I need almost 42 clickable areas...

Comment: use framelayout and add buttons on imageview accordingly.

Comment: @mrinmoy how? For eg: if its for a music player app with play,next,previous,repeat,shuffle controls inside a circle, how can it be aligned?...like, play in the middle and the rest around it?

Answer (score 1):

> Following is the code using which you can achive desired view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/circle">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

**Check the image below:-**

[image]